# Why can't I make a external type appear like an inner type in c++?

Tags: c++, typedef, inner-classes

I want to maintain an existing API that heavily uses an inner enum but I need to separate the enum out into its own type:

This is the current API:

```
class Outer {
public:
    enum Inner {
        FIELD1
    };
};
```

In other words, users currently expect to set `Inner`s by using `Outer::Inner`.
I would like to preserve the name if possible when I make the new outside type:

```
enum Inner {
    FIELD1
};

class Outer {
public:
    typedef Inner Inner;
}
```

However - it gives me a compiler error:

```
./Playground/file0.cpp:23:19: error: declaration of 'typedef enum Inner Outer::Inner' changes meaning of 'Inner' [-fpermissive]
   23 |     typedef Inner Inner;
      |                   ^~~~~
./Playground/file0.cpp:17:6: note: 'Inner' declared here as 'enum Inner'
   17 | enum Inner {
      |      ^~~~~
```

If I just change the name of the enum it all works fine.

```
#include <cassert>

enum Enum {
    FIELD1
};

class Outer {
public:
    typedef Enum Inner;
};

int main() {

    Enum field = Enum::FIELD1;
    Outer::Inner field_alt = Outer::Inner::FIELD1;
    assert(field == field_alt);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not allowed because of the rule [basic.scope.class]/3:

> A name `N` used in a class `S` shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of `S`. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

When you do `typedef Inner Inner;`, you're violating this rule. The first time `Inner` appears on that line, it is a *use* of the name, and is found to refer to the declaration `::Inner`. But once the class is completely defined, `Inner` now refers to the typedef declaration. So the program is ill-formed NDR (GCC is nice enough to give you a diagnostic).

You need to change it to:

```
typedef ::Inner Inner;
```

Now, the unqualified name `Inner` is not being used anymore; instead you are using the qualified name `::Inner`, and its meaning stays the same after the typedef, so there should be no issue.

Comment: I just realized that an inner enum allows variants to be assigned directly off the class like `Outer::FIELD1` - typedef doesn't seem to allow this?

Comment: I guess this may be fodder for an entirely separate question...

Comment: @chub500 You're right, there is no way to do that with current C++. The `using enum` proposal [P1099](https://wg21.link/P1099) would make it possible.

Answer (score 6):

Your `typedef` for `Inner` needs to refer to the `Inner` enum in the *outer scope*, so it should look like this:

```
typedef ::Inner Inner;
```

I generally prefer `using` statements though, which looks like this:

```
using Inner = ::Inner;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/_axUFn)

Comment: Ahh thank you - I was confused by the error message.

Comment: No problem. The error message could be clearer, I guess.

Comment: See @Brian's answer. We're lucky to have any error message at all :) clang doesn't even [diagnose](https://godbolt.org/z/ZWTNKZ) it.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions provided answered my original question, but unfortunately didn't solve my troubles. I hadn't realized at the time that the API in fact took advantage of inner enums.

```
enum Inner {
    FIELD1,
    FIELD2
};

class Base {
public:
    virtual void use(Inner val) = 0;
};

class Outer : public Base {
public:
    virtual void use(Inner val) override;
};

/*
 * Some API that can't change
 */
void someAPI(Outer &inst) {
    inst.use(Outer::FIELD1);
}
```

In other words, the API I needed to maintain was not `Outer::Inner::FIELD1` but `Outer::FIELD1`.

As @Brian pointed out, using a typedef to 'hoist' the Inner enum into Outer could not work in current c++.

Eventually, I found I could put Inner into Base, and the API could be maintained:

```
class Base {
public:
    enum Inner {
        FIELD1,
        FIELD2
    };

    virtual void use(Inner val) = 0;
};

class Outer : public Base {
public:
    virtual void use(Inner val) override;
};

/*
 * Some API that can't change
 */
void someAPI(Outer &inst) {
    inst.use(Outer::FIELD1);
}
```